# output a number in a line with specific string using sed linux

Tags: regex, linux, sed, compare

I have an input like following.

```
Curveplot
Time
Maxima of Curve
Part no.
13 #pts=2
* Minval=   0.000000e+000 at time=        0.000000
* Maxval=   2.237295e+000 at time=        0.001000
   0.000000e+000       0.000000e+000
   9.999999e-004       2.237295e+000
endcurve
```

I want to take get the maximum value out of this file, which is the value after Maxval

```
* Maxval=   2.237295e+000
```

Can someone suggest how to do it with linux sed ?
My output would only be the number  2.237295e+000.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the following one-liner will only display `2.237295e+000`

`sed -nr 's/.*Maxval= *([^ ]*).*/\1/p'`

Regex:

```
Match:
.*      # match any characters
Maxval= # upto 'Maxval='
 *      # match multiple spaces (that is a space followed by *)
([^ ])  # match anything not a space, use brackets to capture (save this) 
.*      # match the rest of line

Replace with:
\1      # the value that a was captured in the first set of brackets.
```

So effectively we substitute the whole line containing the word `Maxval=` by the value of `Maxval`.

*Note: depending on the platform and/or implementation of `sed` the you may need to use `-E` instead of `-r`.*

Comment: You may want to mention that the `-r` flag is GNU only

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
sed -n 's/.*Maxval=\s*\([^ ]*\).*/\1/p' file.txt
```

Results:

```
2.237295e+000
```

Comment: as per op result should also include `* Maxval=`

Comment: @sarathi Maxvel is not required.. I only want that beautiful number. thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Proposal:

`cat test.txt | grep Maxval | sed -e 's/^.*Maxval= *//' -e 's/ at.*$//'
2.237295e+000`

- cat displays the file to stdout
- grep keeps only interesting line
- first sed regex removes begin of line until end of spaces
- second sed regex removes ' at' until end of line

Comment: as per op result should also include `* Maxval=`

Comment: Unnecessary piping both `cat` and `grep` aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/Maxval=/{print $3}' your_file
```

tested below:

```
> cat temp
Curveplot
Time
Maxima of Curve
Part no.
13 #pts=2
* Minval=   0.000000e+000 at time=        0.000000
* Maxval=   2.237295e+000 at time=        0.001000
   0.000000e+000       0.000000e+000
   9.999999e-004       2.237295e+000
endcurve
> awk '/Maxval=/{print $3}' temp
2.237295e+000
```

Comment: The OP: `My output would only be the number 2.237295e+000.`

Answer (score 0):

You could also do it with grep:

```
<infile grep -o 'Maxval= *[^ ]\+' | grep -o '[^ ]\+$'
```

Output:

```
2.237295e+000
```